# Is there a way to running a role until it succeeds in a play?

Tags: ansible, repeat, roles

I have a role name `system_check`. After the system start up, I need to wait until this role succeeds.

Is there a way to run this role repeatedly until it succeeds?

Comment: I believe you can only rerun tasks until they are succeed with certain number of retries. You better identify what task is prone to failure and implement retry mechanism there.

Comment: It is probably a better idea to use the [`wait_for` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) to make sure your machine has (re)booted and play your system_check role afterwards. There is no clean and easy way to do `until` loops on a full role / include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: *"Is there a way to running a role until it succeeds in a play?"*

A: It's not possible. The module [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) says

> Ignores some keywords, like until and retries.

Instead, use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). For example [Use Runner as a standalone command line tool](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/standalone.html#using-runner-as-a-standalone-command-line-tool) and test [artifacts](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy) (rc, status, stdout).

---

For example

```
#!/bin/bash

rcfile=private1/artifacts/ID01/rc
statusfile=private1/artifacts/ID01/status

    ansible-runner -p test.yml -i ID01 run private1
    rc=$(cat $rcfile)
    echo "rc: $rc"

    until [ "0"  == "$rc" ]; do
        ansible-runner -p test.yml -i ID01 run private1
        rc=$(cat $rcfile)
        echo "rc: $rc"
    done


$ tree private1
private1
├── artifacts
├── daemon.log
├── env
│   ├── envvars
│   ├── extravars
│   ├── passwords
│   ├── settings
│   └── ssh_key
├── inventory
│   └── hosts
└── project
    ├── roles
    │   └── testrole
    │       ├── defaults
    │       │   └── main.yml
    │       ├── handlers
    │       │   └── main.yml
    │       ├── meta
    │       │   └── main.yml
    │       ├── README.md
    │       ├── tasks
    │       │   └── main.yml
    │       ├── tests
    │       │   ├── inventory
    │       │   └── test.yml
    │       └── vars
    │           └── main.yml
    └── test.yml
```

Comment: Still having this issue in September 2020. Hope it can be resolved soon. I'm having a timing issue where there are multiple processes running to configure the same servers. When they overlap the Role fails, but restarting the Role would solve the problem.